# Looping through Word document to format text

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-office, ms-word

I have a huge document in which the lines starting with some specific words text style should be changed. I have created an array for all those words and tried formatting the document using For loop. But only the style of first word in the array is getting changed not for all the words in the array.

Below is what I did, please have a look at it and suggest the solution:

```
Sub Variables_NormalTxt()
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Dim oRngFC As Word.Range
    Dim varUbyteNormal As Variant
    Dim ArrayItem As String
    Dim i As Integer
    varUbyteNormal = Array("uword", "ubyte", "bool", "sword", "const", "ulong", "static")
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(varUbyteNormal)
    With oRng.Find
        .Text = varUbyteNormal(i)
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.size = 10
        While .Execute
          oRng.Select
          Set oRngFC = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Line").Range
              oRngFC.Style = "variable normal"
            Wend
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You never use result of the search, just some irrelevant local variables. I fail to see how the style would change even for the first word.

Comment: @GSerg: After the oRng.Select, the built-in bookmark "\Line" will point to the area of interest. It's clumsy, but I haven't got time to do a tested fix of that part right now - perhaps you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this line

```
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
```

into the For loop

i.e.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(varUbyteNormal)
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
```

etc.

Incidentally...

You can remove the line

```
i = 0
```

Your For statement can be generalised to

```
For i = LBound(varUbyteNormal) To UBound(varUbyteNormal)
```

and perhaps others will suggest other improvements.

( ...a further look suggests the following, but it depends on precisley 
what you are looking for)

```
Sub Variables_NormalTxt3()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim varUbyteNormal As Variant
Dim ArrayItem As String
Dim i As Integer
varUbyteNormal = Array("uword", "ubyte", "bool", "sword", "const", "ulong", "static")
For i = LBound(varUbyteNormal) To UBound(varUbyteNormal)
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = varUbyteNormal(i)
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    ' perhaps also...
    .MatchCase = False
    While .Execute
      oRng.Style = "variable normal"
    Wend
  End With
  Set oRng = Nothing
Next 'i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim varUbyteNormal As Variant
varUbyteNormal = Array("uword", "ubyte", "bool", "sword", "const", "ulong", "static")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(varUbyteNormal) To UBound(varUbyteNormal)

  With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions

    With .Font
      .Name = "Times New Roman"
      .Bold = False
      .Size = 10
    End With

    .Text = varUbyteNormal(i)

    With .Replacement
      .ClearFormatting
      .Style = "variable normal"
    End With

    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With

Next
```